# How can I write vim mappings to stdout?

Tags: command-line, bash, vim

I would like to write the output of `:map` to stdout from the vim cli so I can read my vim keymaps from a script and do something with them. How can I accomplish this?

I've tried `vim -c map > out.txt` and `vim -c "map|q" > out.txt` as text cases, but neither work. `:map` opens a pager while inside vim, I think I may need a way to bypass this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33190693/355325 I came up with this:

```
vim -e +"redir>>/dev/stdout | map | redir END" -scq
```

Comment: There's also "`:echoconsole`" if you have a recent enough Vim.